# Branching and swirling mesh on a ring

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, scripting, bezier-curves

I need help constructing this ring.

I thought it would be simpler, but the splitting and recombining of curves that swirl in variously symmetrical ways make the intricacy a little more difficult than I had imagined.

What is the most appropriate technique to efficiently model symmetric branching and swirling curves on a ring?

**Real Information:**

I am attempting to create a printable engagement ring with certain topological requirements.  Due to the symmetry and math involved, I have been attempting to create the ring band beginning with bezier curves, and then applying bezier curves to form surfaces for the mesh.  I am trying to do this completely with the python scripting language, such that I can alter any portion in a modular fashion.

One issue I have run into: branching is not possible with bezier curves.

What I have done:
   1) create curve as long as the ring
   2) bend it to circle
   3) apply surface as taper

After this I am stuck on trying to do the weaving, swirling, and branching around the stone.

I have attempted to apply another simple deform to bend around the top portion of the ring, but this fails miserably, as it does not proportionally fall off - i.e. the entire ring twists around.

I am attempting to emulate the images below:

[image]
[image]
These images are fom Robert Kohr (https://www.robertkohr.com/ring/engagement-ring-design/), but are highly similar to what I am interested in creating.

Here is the function for the band that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
ring_size = 47

def create_curve_object(obj_name, coords):
    # Add the points to curve data
    curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('myCurve', type='CURVE')
    # curveData.dimensions = '3D'
    # curveData.resolution_u = 2

    # map coords to spline
    polyline = curveData.splines.new('NURBS')
    polyline.points.add(len(coords))
    for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
        x,y,z = coord
        polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)

    # create Object
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(obj_name, curveData)

    # make active and add:
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    scn.objects.link(obj)
    scn.objects.active = obj
    obj.select = True
    return obj
def ring_band():
    scn = bpy.context.scene

    # Make Backbone #
    #################

    # band length coordinates
    ring_points = np.linspace(-ring_size/2, ring_size/2, 100)
    coords = [(pt, curl(pt, start_curl = 0.9*ring_points[-1]), 0) for pt in ring_points]
    ring_band = create_curve_object('ring_band', coords)

    # turn the ring standing up
    ring_band.rotation_euler = (np.pi/2, 0, 0)


    # Surface creation #
    ####################
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add()
    band_surface = bpy.context.active_object
    band_surface.name = 'band_surface'
    bez_points = band_surface.data.splines[0].bezier_points

    # Apply surface
    ring_band.data.bevel_object = band_surface



    # Shape surface
    def normal(x, std_dev, mean):
        return 1/(std_dev*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*std_dev**2))

    def f(x):
        std_size = 1.5 # in mm
        deviation_left_side = 12 * normal(x,  std_dev = ring_size/10, mean = -Nda_size/2)
        deviation_right_side = 12 * normal(x,  std_dev = ring_size/10, mean = Nda_size/2)
        deviation_bottom = 20 * normal(x, std_dev = Nda_size/4, mean = 0)

        width_of_ring = std_size - deviation_bottom - deviation_right_side - deviation_left_side
        return width_of_ring

    coords = [(pt, f(pt), 0) for pt in ring_points]

    band_surface_contour = create_curve_object('band_surface_contour', coords)
    ring_band.data.taper_object = band_surface_contour


    # Bend around circle #
    ######################
    # Use empty circle to bend
    band_bender_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("band_bender", None )
    scn.objects.link( band_bender_empty )
    band_bender_empty.empty_draw_type = 'CIRCLE'
    band_bender_empty.rotation_euler = (np.pi/2, 0, 0)

    # TODO: How is this adding to a specific object?
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ring_band
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = 'SIMPLE_DEFORM')
    ring_band.modifiers['SimpleDeform'].deform_method = 'BEND'
    ring_band.modifiers['SimpleDeform'].angle = (2+1/4) * np.pi

    # add array mirror swirl modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = 'ARRAY')
    ring_band.modifiers['Array'].use_object_offset = True




    # Mirror Swirl #
    ################
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type = 'PLAIN_AXES')
    empty_swirl = bpy.context.active_object
    empty_swirl.name = 'empty_swirl'
    # change scale X = -1
    empty_swirl.scale[0] = -1
    empty_swirl.scale[1] = -1

    ring_band.modifiers['Array'].offset_object = empty_swirl
```

Comment: will this tutorial help, https://youtu.be/gVUvnSJ-t3M also have you tried googling it? hope you have success.

Comment: I wouldn't do this all with a script because that kind of work takes a lot of time when you get into the nitty gritty parts like the ones you're stuck on. I would do this work manually from there on. It's been 1/3 of a year, is this question still relevant to you?

Comment: You considered this add on? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ6uIdNnrHk

Answer (score 4):

This is not using Python code. I have to try that method on time, it seems interesting, but using the software itself, such a thing can be achieved.

This is not exactly your plan, but it is an idea and may help other people in modeling.
You can use <kbd>Shift+A</kbd> to build a *cube* as well as a *path*.

[image]

As shown in below figure, enable options *Stretch* and *BoundsClamp* for path. Also use a *Curve Modifier* for cube from the modifiers setting according to the right section of below image. Don't forget to set path as an object of *Curve Modifier*. Now you can bend the cube as a ring; but you need one more step for that to be happen (*Remember this section later for making branches as well*).

[image]

Now select the cube and go to *edit mode* and use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to add more edges to the cube. This helps the cube to bend more smoothly.

[image]

From now on, if you select the path and go to *edit mode*. By bending the path, you can also bend the cube.

So by *editing* the path, you can make something like this:

[image]

You can use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> one more time, select faces from one side, use <kbd>X + F</kbd> to cut the mesh from half; Shear the rest of the mesh; and finally use *Mirror Modifier*.

[image]

Now by selecting one face and enabling the Proportional Editing Mode with <kbd>O</kbd> and using <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> keys; By rotating or moving one face according to other neighboring faces; you can make the surface of the ring.

[image]

You can use Mirroring again to make other side of the ring; and also *ExtraMesh Addon* to make a diamond quickly.

[image]

Now the question (Branching):

Select the ring; go to *edit mode*; Select a face and *Extrude* it using <kbd>E</kbd>; now you can have an extra object; select that object and extract that mesh using <kbd>P</kbd> key. Use <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> to make more Edges in new object. Here again, the same method of making a ring must be repeated from the beginning, and by making a path and *curve modifier*, you can create a new branch.

[image]

Now shape the new branch by editing the second path object:

[image]

Now you should merge the branch with the ring; select both of them and use <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>; and join verts by selecting each pair and using <kbd>Alt + M</kbd>

[image]

And the final result:

[image]

---

I tested Python in Blender for the first time and I can say it was great. It took me 2-3 hours to get used to it, but I was able to make branches randomly.

I did not try to make a complete ring with the code, it usually takes a lot of time, and later I test this on time and update the answer, but as an example, this code is not a bad idea for generating branches.

```
import bpy
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from bpy import context, data, ops
from mathutils import Matrix

#____________________________________________#

def eulerToDegree(euler):
    return ( (euler) / (2 * pi) ) * 360

#____________________________________________#


for material in bpy.data.materials:
    material.user_clear()
    bpy.data.materials.remove(material)


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)


for obj in bpy.data.curves:
    bpy.data.curves.remove(obj)


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0,0,0))
bpy.context.object.data.name = "RingMesh"
bpy.context.object.name = "Ring"

bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(.3, .3, .1))
bpy.context.object.location = (0,0,0)
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
bpy.data.objects["Ring"].modifiers["Array"].relative_offset_displace[0]=0
bpy.data.objects["Ring"].modifiers["Array"].relative_offset_displace[1]=0
bpy.data.objects["Ring"].modifiers["Array"].relative_offset_displace[2]=1
bpy.data.objects["Ring"].modifiers["Array"].count=100

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CURVE')



# Create path and enter edit mode.
ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add(radius=1,location=(0,0,0),enter_editmode=True)
bpy.data.curves[0].name="RingPath"
bpy.context.active_object.name="RingPath"
bpy.data.curves["RingPath"].use_stretch=True
bpy.data.curves["RingPath"].use_deform_bounds=True



# Means no subdivision
ops.curve.subdivide(number_cuts=0)              


# make a random deformed branch
# ops.transform.vertex_random(offset=1.0, uniform=0.1, normal=0.0, seed=101)
ops.transform.vertex_random(offset=1.0, uniform=0.1, normal=0.0,       seed=random.randint(1,1000))


ops.transform.resize(value=(2,2,2))
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler = (0,math.radians(90),0)


# Return to object mode.
ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') #exit edit_mode

bpy.data.objects["Ring"].modifiers["Curve"].object=bpy.data.objects["RingPath"]
```

And this is the result of random branches (Blender 2.79):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the best way to do this is to make a bezier curve to use as a guide and then add points to the original torus.

I would also try to not build the whole ring and instead split the ring into symmetrical pieces and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to create a duplication.  If you change one part of the symmetrical pieces the others will change with it and it will make the job much easier.

With using Python scripting, I do not know how to use this to your advantage.