# Tips on modelling Jewelry ring

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and I am trying to learn how to model rings from reference files that were done in Rhino (not by me). How I modeled this was using a Curve Path before mirroring it to create a ring. Then scaling the vertices to taper the ends.

I am having issues figuring out how to cut a hole in the surface of the ring to match the reference.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: model]

[image: vertices]

Comment: You might want to look at these.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=modelling+jewery+in+blender

Comment: Okay i will thank you !

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74902/how-to-align-duplication-correct-way https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123014/branching-and-swirling-mesh-on-a-ring/204291#204291